# Return Field as Long Date disabled in SharePoint Designer WorkFlow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have SharePoint 2013 Workflow that getting Today date to Workflow Variable and Check the Day, but when I try to return workflow variable as Long Date Designer is not allowing to choose and drop down is grayed out

[image]

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1):

What’s the action you used to return workflow variable? Different action can only return certain type of Date value.

Per my test, I can get the Long Date type of data via Log to History action.

[image]

Comment: I was using add days and out variable. thank you.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue by using "Add time to date" action. It's the default behavior.

Comment: Thank you Fiona. How check If the variable Contains some certain characters? Ex: if today is Monday I want do some process in my workflow.